# How to create multiple checkboxes grouped by fieldsets in Cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, web, checkbox, cakephp-3.0

I'm having a problem following this documentation :

[Cakephp3 Cookbook - Form - Creating Select Pickers](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-select-pickers)
I tried the 'multiple checkboxes' part :

```
$options = [
   'Group 1' => [
      'Value 1' => 'Label 1',
      'Value 2' => 'Label 2'
   ],
   'Group 2' => [
      'Value 3' => 'Label 3'
   ]
];
echo $this->Form->select('field', $options, ['multiple' => 'checkbox']);
```

but the output was an error like this :

```
Notice (8): Array to string conversion [CORE/src/View/StringTemplate.php, line 238]
```

it's like telling me that the value of the array should be a string instead of an Array, but is there anyway to make this work ? Please can anyone help me solve this problem ?

Comment: I don't think it is (currently) possible to groups with multiple checkbox, the groups only work with standard select.

Comment: is that so, too bad then, thanks @Holt

Comment: The documentation currently says "If you would like to generate a select with optgroups, just pass data in hierarchical format. This works on multiple checkboxes and radio buttons too, but instead of optgroups wraps elements in fieldsets". I tried this with CakePHP 3.1, and it didn't generate an error, but it also didn't seem to generate expected output. Using the `['multiple' => 'checkbox']` option on the select call resulted in too many checkboxes being created, and using `['options' => $options, 'multiple' => 'checkbox']` on an input call resulted in too few... I didn't test it beyond that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Holt already mentioned in the comments, what you're doing there is simply not supported. If you think this might be useful, you can **[suggest it as an enhancement](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues)** over at GitHub.

What you can do for now, is either building it half-way manually, like for example

```
foreach ($options as $group => $groupOptions) {
    $legend = $this->Html->tag('legend', $group);
    $checkboxes = $this->Form->select($group, $groupOptions, [
        'name' => 'field',
        'multiple' => 'checkbox'
    ]);
    echo $this->Html->tag('fieldset', $legend . $checkboxes);
}
```

or, for better reusability, create a custom widget that can handle such structures.

See **[Cookbook > View > Helpers > Form > Adding Custom Widgets](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#adding-custom-widgets)**